# ¿Como convierto una matriz de confusión grande en una matriz 2x2 en python? Todo esto siendo ambas un dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, matriz

Tengo un dataframe con una matriz de confusión (5x5)  con los siguientes datos:

[image: Matriz de confusión de vocales]

Querría convertir esta matriz (5x5) en 5 matrices de confusión (2x2), una para cada una de las letras a,e,i,o,u).
Por ejemplo, para la letra "a", tendría en la posición [1,1] tendría las veces que tanto la predicción como el resultado eran "a" (acierto). En la posición [2,1], tendría las veces que el resultado no es "a", pero el programa ha predicho que sí lo es (error). En la posición [1,2], tendría las veces que el resultado es "a", pero el programa no ha reconocido a (error). En la posición [2,2], tendría las veces que ni la predicción ni el resultado ha sido "a", es decir, el resto de casos.

Algo así como lo que se ve en la imagen adjunta.

[image: Ejemplo matriz de confusión 2x2]

Para llegar a la matriz de confusión de la primera imagen, he realizado este código:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

working_path = os.getcwd() #sirve para establecer en qué carpeta estamos trabajando (ruta), ahora todos los archivos q se encuentren en esa carpeta solo los tenemos que llamar con su nombre

df = pd.read_csv("salida.txt",delimiter="\t") #Hacemos un dataframe, importando el archivo txt separado por tabuladores

df.rename(columns={'Number of Syllables': 'NSyllables'}, inplace = True) #Cambiamos (acortamos) nombres de la columna que indica el nº de sílabas

confusion_matrixV = pd.crosstab(df['TargetV'], df['RespV'], rownames=['Target'], colnames=['Response'], margins = True); #Matriz de confusión para VOCALES
```

introducir el código aquí

No sé cómo podría a partir de este dataframe crear el otro 2x2, he supuesto que mediante un bucle for que empezase así, pero no lo se hacer:

```
for index, row in confusion_matrixV.iterrows():
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero voy a crear una matriz como la que muestras:

```
import pandas as pd

confusion_matrixV = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Targets": ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u"),
      "a": (158, 0, 0, 0, 0),
      "e": (0, 104, 0, 1, 0),
      "i": (0, 3, 87, 0, 0),
      "o": (0, 0, 0, 123, 2),
      "u": (0, 0, 0, 2, 44)}
)

confusion_matrixV.set_index("Targets", inplace=True)
confusion_matrixV.columns.name = "Response"
```

> ```
> >>> confusion_matrixV
>
> Response  a   e   i   o   u
> Targets                   
>       a   158 0   0   0   0
>       e   0   104 3   0   0
>       i   0   0   87  0   0
>       o   0   1   0   123 2
>       u   0   0   0   2   44
> ```

Asumiendo que tu tabla cruzada tiene esa estructura exactamente, para cada letra podemos definir:

- **Verdaderos positivos**: es el valor de la celda en la diagonal principal de esa columna.
- **Falsos positivos**:  es la suma de todos los valores de la columna menos la celda de la diagonal principal.
- **Verdaderos negativos**: es la suma de todos los valores de la matriz menos los incluidos en la fila y columna de esa letra.
- **Falsos negativos**: es la suma de los valores de la fila con ese mismo índice menos el valor de la celda de la diagonal principal.

Por tanto, vectorizando operaciones, podemos obtener una matriz para cada uno de los anteriores valores. Luego basta con generar un dataframe para cada uno:

```
import numpy as np

verdaderos_positivos = np.diag(confusion_matrixV)
falsos_positivos = confusion_matrixV.sum(axis=0) - verdaderos_positivos
falsos_negativos = confusion_matrixV.sum(axis=1) - verdaderos_positivos
verdaderos_negativos = (
    confusion_matrixV.to_numpy().sum() - 
    (verdaderos_positivos + falsos_positivos + falsos_negativos)
)

for dato, vp, fp, vn, fn in zip(
    confusion_matrixV.columns,
    verdaderos_positivos, falsos_positivos,
    verdaderos_negativos, falsos_negativos):

    frame = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
        {"Positive(1)": (vp, fp), "Negative(0)": (fn, vn)},
        orient="Index",
        columns=("Positive(1)", "Negative(0)")
    )
    frame.index.name = f'Predicted Values for "{dato}"'
    frame.columns.name = f'Actual values for "{dato}"'
    print(frame, "\n")
```

> ```
> Actual values for "a"     Positive(1)  Negative(0)
> Predicted Values for "a"                          
> Positive(1)                       158            0
> Negative(0)                         0          366 
>
> Actual values for "e"     Positive(1)  Negative(0)
> Predicted Values for "e"                          
> Positive(1)                       104            1
> Negative(0)                         3          416 
>
> Actual values for "i"     Positive(1)  Negative(0)
> Predicted Values for "i"                          
> Positive(1)                        87            3
> Negative(0)                         0          434 
>
> Actual values for "o"     Positive(1)  Negative(0)
> Predicted Values for "o"                          
> Positive(1)                       123            2
> Negative(0)                         3          396 
>
> Actual values for "u"     Positive(1)  Negative(0)
> Predicted Values for "u"                          
> Positive(1)                        44            2
> Negative(0)                         2          476
> ```

En vez de imprimir, puedes meter cada DataFrame en una lista o dónde quieras.